# Apache 1 timeout reading large xml file

Tags: php, apache, http

Using an opencart plugin I am getting these errors in my apache error log

```
Read POST information timed out

(22)Invalid argument: client stopped connection before rvputs completed
```

I just wanted to verify this is due to a client side http connection timeout when reading a large xml file.

Is there any configuration I can change server side to prevent this? Since it's related to a client side timeout I am doubtful.

My idea is to remove the http requirement altogether. I'm thinking of just running a cron script, or starting a process and not waiting for it to finish like here. [Don't wait for the process to exit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/136429/dont-wait-for-the-process-to-exit)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Outputting data to the browser periodically fixed this. Apache was loading a request for about 10 minutes without output causing the browser to close the connection on the client side. I just sent periodic status updates using echo and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Put `set_time_limit(0)` on top of the request page. 0 is meant for max possible time.

Comment: Yes I did that with no luck. The problem from the logs is the client stops the connection to the server due to system http connection timeout. I was wondering if there's a server side setting which will override this.

Comment: Is server is in your hand or is it a remote server? if it is in your hand, try to increase the max connection time in your web server.

Comment: It seems to be an issue with the php code. It uses header to send a 302 status and a new location. Its opencart using the built in redirect. I will keep debugging and keep this updated.