# exec causes perpetual load

Tags: php

I noticed exec and shell_exec is causing perpetual loading.

Basically, I'm trying to do something as simple as loading a PHP script in the background. When I try to do that, it just loads and loads.

My code is as follows

```
exec('php test.php -- '.escapeshellarg($param1).'  > /dev/null  ');
```

I first thought it was my other script, so I pointed it to a file with just:

```
echo $agrv[1];
```

But it still loads perpetually.

Comment: Loads and loads what? Your "question" isn't clear

Comment: Exactly what is this `test.php` script doing? Exec() will not return until the process you've spawned (php running test.php) exits. If test.php is (say) requesting input, it'll just sit there forever because you never provide that input.

Comment: Why are you even calling `exec('php test.php ...')`? Why not `include(test.php)`? And why is it taking forever to execute? What is `test.php` doing?

Comment: You keep saying that word, "perpetual", I don't think it means what you think it means.

Answer (score 0):

[Don't wait for the process to exit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/136429/dont-wait-for-the-process-to-exit)

exec() waits for the process to give an exit code. The link I provided above may help you.

Oh, and since you tagged Linux for whatever reason, I assume you're on a Linux distro.

You could consider this, aswell:
https://www.php.net/pcntl_fork