# Multiple sequential http requests without closing connection

Tags: php, http, curl

How can I send multiple http requests sequentially to a server ? 
I want to send a GET request to an api `GET /api/parameter` and dont want to send `Connection: Close`. Then upon receiving the response I want to send another request?

How can I do it with curl?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Persistent/keepalive HTTP with the PHP Curl library?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/972925/persistent-keepalive-http-with-the-php-curl-library)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found this.  **Curl automatically utilizes previous opened connection**. Just make sure that you dont create a new handle.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use HTTP 1.1 like this or the server will close the connection anyway:

```
GET /api/parameter HTTP/1.1
```

Answer (score 0):

See curl_multi_exec:

http://ca.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-multi-exec.php

Hope this helps.