# curl through an already open socket

Tags: php, sockets, curl

I wonder if there's a way to use `curl` trhough an already open socket, something like, adapting this:

```
<?php
$fp = fsockopen("www.example.com", 80, $errno, $errstr, 30);
if (!$fp) {
    echo "$errstr ($errno)<br />\n";
} else {
    $out = "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\n";
    $out .= "Host: www.example.com\r\n";
    $out .= "Connection: Close\r\n\r\n";
    fwrite($fp, $out);
    while (!feof($fp)) {
        echo fgets($fp, 128);
    }
    fclose($fp);
}
?>
```

to use `curl_exec()` instead of `fgets($fp, 128)`

(or, any other way to use `curl()` over the same stream all the time, my goal is to read the twitter stream api)

Thank you

Comment: Except you want to combine curl and `fgets` together

Comment: No, cURL has its own internal socket handling. What is the real issue you are facing? Why do you want to initiate a socket for cURL while cURL can do that itself pretty good? What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: Twitter stream api forces clients to use a single connection and stay there listening "forever", so I need curl() to use the same connection always rather than connect/read/disconnect. Also, I want curl instead of fwrite($fp, $out) as I use a class that uses curl and OAuth, which I need for Twitter API

Comment: [cURL by default reuses its connections](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/972925/persistent-keepalive-http-with-the-php-curl-library).

Comment: I can give example if you want

Comment: I'll give it a try, then. I have to leave this task till thursday so... if your example is already written it's always welcome, if not... then as you wish, I will go on with this in 2 days. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might work for you since you are dealing with Twitter Stream API

```
set_time_limit(0);
$ch = curl_init();
echo "<pre>";
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://sitestream.twitter.com/2b/site.json");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, 'cgets');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BUFFERSIZE, 128);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, 'user:password');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 1000000);
curl_exec($ch);

function cgets($ch, $string) {
    $length = strlen($string);
    printf("Received %d byte\n", $length);
    flush();
    return $length;
}
```

Comment: But I'm using version 1.1 of the api so I need OAuth, plus, there should be an _infinite_ loop somwhere

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to force cURL to use an existing socket in PHP. While cURL pools and reuses the connections internally, it cannot be forced to use the same one all the time, or never close a connection it opened.

You can checkout [Phirehose](https://github.com/fennb/phirehose) (which is a PHP interface to the streaming APIs) or if that's not good enough, do some shopping on the [Twitter Libraries](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/twitter-libraries#php) list - chances are somebody already solved your problem in PHP and packaged it.

Still, using the stream API sound strange from PHP. Is this on a web server, or a stand-alone long-running script?

Comment: It's in a webserver, maybe it will go in a cron script