# Sending Notification to millions of devices from PHP

Tags: php, android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I have more than 1 millions of devices with a token . I want to send notification to all of the devices without a time out. I have a the php code but it only sends to 300 devices before timing out.

```
function _send_notification($registatoin_ids = '', $message = '') {
$url = 'https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send';
$fields = array(
    'registration_ids' => $registatoin_ids,
    'data' => $message,
);
//pr($fields);
$headers = array(
    'Authorization: key=' . $this->GOOGLE_API_KEY,
    'Content-Type: application/json',
    'Connection: keep-alive',
    'Keep-Alive: 300'
);
$ch = curl_init();
// Set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECT_ONLY, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10000); // drop connection after 10000 seconds
// Disabling SSL Certificate support temporarly
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));
// Execute post
$result = curl_exec($ch);
if ($result === FALSE) {
    die('Curl failed: ' . curl_error($ch));
}
// Close connection
curl_close($ch);
return $result; //exit;
}
```

Please help me out

Comment: hello sir ! i m facing the same issue what u  have faced ? can you help me what  u did to get the result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this just after starting funciton

```
set_time_limit (0);
```

Answer (score 0):

`'Keep-Alive: 300'` will make `curl` to keep using the same context of `curl connection` upto max `300` requests.

To solve the problem, `CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE` might be helpful. have a look at 
[reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/982556/1288725)

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
set_time_limit( 0 );
ini_set( 'memory_limit', '250M' )
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php

However this is not a real solution to the problem, you might want to set it up as a cron job or look into a queuing system like RabitMq, depending how often you need to do this, and how long it takes to run them all..

p.s. memory_limit is just there in case you hit the memory limit, not sure how efficient your code is in that regard.

Comment: Thank @ArtisiticPhoenix . I used this but i faced the same problem. Using cron it was possible . I tried and that is working but i want it without using cron. Because using cron i have to check when i have to stop the cron .

Comment: You could build a simple queuing system in the database, where do you get the list of devices to send from?

Comment: Basically you would store a record with a status flag, and then run 2 cron jobs, one sends out the jobs, and flags it as done when complete ( or ignores them and just dies if already complete ), then the second one would reset the status flag once a day or week or whatever you need.