# request pool for php curl

Tags: php, session, curl

My PHP server (A) needs to make an http request to another server (B) each time it's called.
I'm familiar with the usual use case for using curl in PHP

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($ch, $curlOptions);
$responseBody = curl_exec($ch);
$curlErrorCode = curl_errno($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

However I'm calling the same server (B) every time. Is there a way to keep the connections between A and B open (keepalive)? Maybe some sort of connection pool?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Persistent/keepalive HTTP with the PHP Curl library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/972925/persistent-keepalive-http-with-the-php-curl-library)

Comment: ^ this requires the server which receives the request to have keep alive enabled.

Comment: @MartinZeitler thanks for pointing that out. this partially answers the question. But as the answer points out the **cURL handle must be reused**. sounds like i'd have to implement some connection pool class... that initiates the handler once. is there some sort of example or module for this?

Answer (score 0):

Implementing socket handling will be great if you want two servers to communicate with each other.
http://php.net/manual/en/sockets.examples.php

Comment: this is a `cURL` specific question; see https://curl.haxx.se/ ...and if, then rather `WSS` protocol.