# Detect what part of MySQL queries works via mysql and mysqli

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Can I somehow detect how much MySQL queries performed via old `mysql` and how much via `mysqli` connections.

My basic work is recode, refactor and support old projects. I migrate from procedural to OOP style and from `mysql` to `mysqli`. I need to know how much old requests left from old coders (code is messy and crazy as usual to calculate this in code directly).

Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like you might want to be [*profiling*](http://www.xdebug.org/docs/profiler) your app... Though this introduces serious performance penalties.

Answer (score 0):

mysqli has http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.get-connection-stats.php
and for any driver you can run `show status like 'Com\_%';` query.

I see no point in such numbers though, for the task provided.

Answer (score -1):

You can override both methods with [override_function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2092179/how-to-show-running-mysql-queries-in-php) and [log](http://php.net/manual/es/function.error-log.php) whatever you need.