# Send multiple xml requests in parallel in PHP? Possible?

Tags: php

I have a script that makes calls to an XML api on a remote server.  Currently my script sends 10 requests serially to the remote server.  It fully processes each request before sending the next one.  This is a huge bottleneck for my server at the moment since each API request can take up to a second each.  Since most of the time is spent waiting for the remote server to respond, I'm wondering if/how I can send the requests in parallel so that all 10 requests use the same one second latency instead of ten one second latencies...

I thought about calling the script 10 times using a system command and running them in the background to effectively create 10 processes, but I'm not sure if that's the best way to do it.  I figure this problem has probably been solved before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use curl. See [here in the manual](http://www.php.net/curl_multi_exec).

You can also use [non-blocking I/O](http://wezfurlong.org/blog/2005/may/guru-multiplexing).

Answer (score 0):

If you can use system command, then it is possible.

1. Create php scripts what do the request and write the response data to files (10 files in total)
2. Write a php script that call system command to run those 10 php script above, then wait for all executions is done
3. Read the response data from files

Answer (score 0):

PHP doesn't support threads, but you use [curl_multi](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-exec.php).

That will send your requests in parallel. This is a good solution because most of the time you are waiting on the network anyway.

If you design carefully (use a queue for urls, issue a  processing callback when each one is done) you won't have to wait until the longest request is finished

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is probably asynchronous calls.  It can be done a couple of different ways in PHP depending on the version you're using.  Some great information on it in this question:
[Asynchronous PHP calls?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/124462/asynchronous-php-calls)