# Sending post request and do not wait for reply and continue php script

Tags: php, post, reply

I need to send post request from php whithout waiting for response .

CURL has no this abillity and also wget.

I am sending many post requests to apple push servers and reply from this server is very slow and i dont need the response.

thx for help

Comment: Is this for a web based PHP script/page?

Answer (score 4):

From the wget man page:

> -b
>
> --background
>
> Go to background immediately after
>   startup.  If no output file is
>   specified via the -o, output is
>   redirected to wget-log.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/124462/asynchronous-php-calls). It has a code sample for what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Put the requests into a queue (a database perhaps), and have a separate script which runs periodically and executes requests from the queue.

Answer (score 0):

You could try setting CURLOPT_TIMEOUT. That wac curl_exec() will stop if it takes too long.