# Run a url to send sms in the background?

Tags: php, url, sms

when I approve an order, it redirects to a confirmation page which adds details to dbase, send email etc... Now, I want that to also send sms automatically by loading the gateway url
the url open in browser but I want it to run in the background.

For now, I put a link where I click and it opens in new browser...

Please help

Answer (score 3):

If I understand correctly you send the SMS by opening an URL. You could achieve this by opening the url with cURL in a php file:

```
// create a new cURL resource
$ch = curl_init();

// set URL and other appropriate options
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.example.com/");

// grab URL and pass it to the browser
curl_exec($ch);

// close cURL resource, and free up system resources
curl_close($ch);
```

for more info see: http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php

Comment: @Naira Alternatively, if the SMS-sending page takes some time to load and you don't want your page to be delayed by that, you could run something like `exec("wget '$url' > /dev/null");`, assuming your server runs on linux (redirecting output anywhere makes `exec` to run in background, without hanging PHP until the program finishes).

Comment: I tried the curl and sure it could have worked cos the gateway returned code 1800 which means sms not sent. I coped the exact url into my browser and got code 1801 which means message sent and I received the message. What do you think could be left?

Comment: I also tried the exec() and got this response "Warning: exec() has been disabled for security reasons in /home/xxxx/public_html/allnews.php on line 23
"

Comment: thanks a lot for this answer... you made my day... i was able to execute and send msg via this script... Note: the message should have every space replaced with '%20'... else will throw bad response.. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

See [Asynchronous PHP calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/124462/asynchronous-php-calls) - this should be what you need.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Tasks](http://github.com/jamm/Tasks) module for delayed (background) execution.
You can put there sms and email sending, and your main page will not have to wait their execution.

Comment: Not sure about Windows because Task manager should be launched by cron or something else (task scheduler in windows, I guess).

Answer (score 0):

It may not be what your looking for but is worth mentioning. Why dont you just CC the email to your carriers SMS email?

**T-Mobile:** phonenumber@tmomail.net
**Virgin Mobile:** phonenumber@vmobl.com
**Cingular:** phonenumber@cingularme.com
**Sprint:** phonenumber@messaging.sprintpcs.com
**Verizon:** phonenumber@vtext.com
**Nextel:** phonenumber@messaging.nextel.com

Comment: HA, IDK. Thats under the assumption his carrier is a main US company, and the texts are for his own usage and not a user.