# Saving Images Async CodeIgniter PHP

Tags: php, android, ios, codeigniter, imagemagick

I am using ImageMagick in Codeigniter 2.x to save multiple copies of an image for a social site. After each crop, it sends the image to an AWS s3 bucket.

I am wondering if there is any way to make this process Asynchronous in PHP to keep the user from having to wait for 4 crops and saves before returning the response.

Comment: What response(s) are you trying to send back to the user?

Comment: the end client just needs a 200 OK. currently the setup is Request + image -> API -> ImageMagick -> API (with image name to store in DB) -> 200 Response to user

Comment: There is this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14750264/asynchronous-php-call-which-runs-a-controller-method

Comment: That worked cleanly. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can introduce a queuing system in your codeigniter project. If you are on AWS, one option is to send a message to SQS to indicate an image has been uploaded, and you can process the images asynchronously without holding up the user, [`https://aws.amazon.com/articles/PHP/1602`](https://aws.amazon.com/articles/PHP/1602)

You can also use AWS Lambda taking a serverless approach, [http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/walkthrough-s3-events-adminuser-create-test-function-create-function.html](https://clifff.com/2015/10/01/2015-failed-experiments-with-aws-lambda/)

or Cloudinary (http://cloudinary.com/) offers a great cloud solution that will provide a very flexible image resizing/processing service for most projects for free.