# Magento HTTP request- do not wait for a response

Tags: magento, httprequest

I am writing a Magento extension that will export orders to a 3rd party upon cart submission.
I did an equivalent plugin for WordPress a few months ago. The way I did it was that everytime a user would submit an order, I would create a single WordPress cron job (`wp_schedule_single_event`) so that there was no delay for the user (and that the export job would run in the background due to the way `WP-Cron` works).

Now, this worked great, and I would like to do something similar with Magento. Magento does have a CRON, but it doesn't seem to have a way of scheduling single events. I was thinking of doing the following:

1. When an order is submitted, write this order number into a table.
2. Create a request to a php file that I have created which handles querying the above mentioned table and exporting the orders.

My questions are:

1. How do I send a request to a php file through PHP that basically kicks off the page load, but doesn't wait for a response?
2. Are there any flaws in my process that I am missing?

Answer (score 1):

The closest you can get to that behavior in PHP (that I've seen) [is using sockets, (per this previous Stack Overflow question)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/124462/asynchronous-php-calls) although it'll be impossible to tell if your request finished or not.

Comment: Thanks I will take a look. I'm not at all worried if the request finishes all not as the script will log failure/success into another table. Alan Storm... if its you, I was just reading your articles.. they are fantastic!