# Magento- Do not wait for response from controller

Tags: php, magento

I am building a Magento plugin that exports orders to a 3rd party system via web service.
I am possibly going to use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/124462/asynchronous-php-calls) method to export my orders so that the user doesn't have to wait for the order to export, which basically pings a webpage but doesn't wait for the response.

Now, If I am using this in my magento site, what address would I be sending the request to, that would instantiate my model (and kick off the export process)? Would I create a controller and a frontend route, and simply use the HTTP address of this page?

Comment: You would have to consider the security implications of creating a route from a URL to such code.  Better to run it as a CLI PHP script.

Comment: Thanks- thats the sort of feedback I'm looking for. I really want to avoid a CLI script as I want this plugin to be plug & play.