# async PHP cron job? is it possible?

Tags: php, asynchronous, cron

I need to write a cron (php) script to get the html result from several websites.

Let's say my database has 50 websites records (ie. http://www.somewebsite.com/page.php). So the cron job will be set to run every x mins. When it's running, it will load the records from database, check the status of each websites then get the HTML result back from it then analysis it.

My concern is, if the website from n'th record is not responding, or it takes some time to load (ie. oversea website), then n+1's record won't be run, not until n'th record is finished, then this cron job will take a while to finish.

If I execute the script on a browser, then it can be easily handled by using ajax async, however it's a cron job, so I have no idea how to handle this situation.

Comment: Cron jobs are already asynchronous.

Comment: can you please explain how? if my cron.php is running, and if line 20 is supposes to get the website html, how can it execute line 21 without finishing what line 20 is doing?

Comment: I think you are confusing terms.  Cron jobs are executed asynchronously.  You are asking how to place asynchronous HTTP requests from *within* PHP, which has nothing at all to do with Cron.  At best, your question is unclear.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Asynchronous PHP calls?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/124462/asynchronous-php-calls)

Comment: guess I didn't describe the problem properly. Thanks for the async php link :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you can do, 
Run the sh script from crontab and in the script invoke .php program that takes care of async tasks.

Answer (score 0):

I think its better to move to other language if there is need of 'Async'. It's a major upgrade to how you would create the overall system architecture. So this is a major upgrade to any PHP developer as myself spending a lot in PHP and looking into NodeJS for better solutions. And PHP does not support such need internally or from the core yet, although the term 'Aync' is introduced.