# Curl with multithreading

Tags: php, multithreading, curl

I am scraping data from an URL using cURL

```
for ($i = 0; $i < 1000000; $i++) {

    $curl_handle = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://example.com?page='.$i);
    curl_exec($curl_handle);
    curl_close($curl_handle);

    // some code to save the HTML page on HDD
}
```

I wanted to know if there is some way that I could speed up the process? Maybe multithreading? How could I do it?

Comment: You can implement something like async call here is the link -> https://segment.com/blog/how-to-make-async-requests-in-php/

Comment: Also SO answer @http://stackoverflow.com/questions/124462/asynchronous-php-calls

Answer (score 2):

cURL Multi does not make parallel requests, it makes asynchronous requests.

The documentation was wrong until 5 minutes ago, it will take some time for the corrected documentation to be deployed and translated.

Asynchronous I/O (using something like the cURL Multi API) is the simplest thing to do, however, it can only make requests asynchronously; the processing of data once downloaded, for example writing to disk would still cause lots of blocking I/O, similarly further processing of the data (parsing json for example) would occur synchronously, in a single thread of execution.

Multi-threading is the other option, this requires that you have a thread safe build of PHP and the pthreads extension installed.

Multi-threading has the advantage that all processing can be done for each download and subsequent actions in parallel, fully utilizing all the CPU cores available.

What is best depends largely on how much processing of downloaded data your code must perform, and even then can be considered a matter of opinion.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for the `curl_multi_*` set of functions: "Allows the processing of multiple cURL handles in parallel".

Take a look at the [complete example on the `curl_multi_init()` page](http://php.net/curl_multi_init#example-4335).

Check out these articles for more information about how `curl_multi_exec()` works:

- http://technosophos.com/2012/10/26/php-and-curlmultiexec.html
- http://www.somacon.com/p537.php