# Is it possible to implement a fire-and-forget web request to an Apache webserver with PHP while processing a request

Tags: php, apache, message-queue, asynchttpclient

I have a webrequest processing real-time calls (needs processing time within 100ms) and certain operations are taking a long time (250ms). I was checking whether it's possible to fire-and-forget a web request while processing the original request? So far, I have gathered:

1. One can make an async http post in php using:
       [Asynchronous PHP calls?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/124462/asynchronous-php-calls/2924987#2924987)
2. Apache stops processing as soon as the request connection is
   closed:
   http://activelamp.com/blog/development/asynchronous-php-with-message-queues/
3. Use php threads vs message-queues (similar to #2)

If it is possible, please let me know how and point me to the source.

Comment: yes it is possible.  You can use `curl` on linux via something like `exec()` (command line) with the  `> /dev/null &` at the end of the command to detach the shell.

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix Can you please tell me how to accomplish this if yes. Thanks.

Comment: I would try something like `exec('curl http://example.com/index.php > /dev/null &')`  I never tried it before, but it might work.  This will probably only work on Linux.

Comment: thanks, one of the comments to this answer points your suggestion:https://stackoverflow.com/a/124557/376742

exec("curl $url > /dev/null 2>&1 &");

Comment: wget is different then curl, but they do both make HTTP requests.  Either should work if your not worried about the return.  Just don't put user supplied data into `exec` without using `escapeshellarg` or similar,  https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/47434/what-is-the-difference-between-curl-and-wget

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @ArtisticPhoenix posted on the comments, one can use:

```
exec("curl $url > /dev/null 2>&1 &");
```

For scaling issues, I didn't go further with that solution.