# Async get request

Tags: php, asynchronous, get

I'm looking for a way to do asynchronous GET requests in PHP with callbacks, similar to JavaScript's `fetch` API:

```
fetch(url).then(Response => Response.text()).then(console.log);
```

I'm trying to do it like this:

```
aysnc_gets($urls_array, {echo $result;});
```

Or I could make a single async request at a time with a simple loop.

I've looked all over and found nothing that works. How would I do this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make asynchronous HTTP requests in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/124462/how-to-make-asynchronous-http-requests-in-php)

Comment: @FelippeDuarte No. See my comments on each answer there.

Comment: You mean comments like _“I don't understand this at all...”_? Yeah, those are really helpful. Plus, please don’t direct us to _other_ questions, to gather your requirements from various comments strewn all over the place there. Make your own question self-contained - explain what you already tried, and what your specific requirements are, _here_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[I found this website that details `curl_multi_*` functions, which worked for me.](https://webkul.com/blog/simultaneous-curl-requests-in-php/)